# Fill factor For B-trees. Why fill factor is respected when extending the index at the right and not in other case (except during index creation)?

Tags: postgresql, fillfactor

I'm trying to understand the fillfactor in case of btree indexes. From the postgres documentation:

> For B-trees, leaf pages are filled to this percentage during initial
> index build, and also when extending the index at the right (adding
> new largest key values).

Firstly, what does it mean *extending the index at the right*? Does it means split the rightest leaf in the B-tree? (images would be helpful).

Why the fillfactor is taken in consideration in this case, and is not taken in consideration only when the index is created?

As far as I know, postgresql will take in consideration the fill factor during the creation. For example, with a fill factor = 50%, right after index creation, the leaves will be 50% full at the most, then, with new insertions, this parameter is not respected (expected for this "right extension").

Answer (score 1):

The rightmost leaf page of a B-tree index is the one with the largest value in it:

```
                        +---------+
                        |root page|
                        +---------+
                        /          \
                       /            \
           +----------+              +----------+
           |inner page|              |inner page|
           +----------+              +----------+
            /        \                 /       \
           /          \               /         \
+-----------+  +-----------+  +-------------+  +-------------+
|1 3 ... 100|  |101 ... 900|  |1000 ... 2000|  |2000 ... 5000|
+-----------+  +-----------+  +-------------+  +-------------+
  leaf page      leaf page       leaf page    rightmost leaf page
```

Since it is a common case that new values are inserted into the rightmost page, for example with auto-incrementing sequence values or with ever-increasing timestamps, insertions there are treated differently, much like when an index is created.  The rationale is that such insertions are usually caused by `INSERT`s rather than by `UPDATE`s.

If the rightmost page were treated like all others, then auto-incremented primary keys or time series would often create a densely packed index, regardless of the `fillfactor` setting. Then the first `UPDATE` that is not [HOT](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/hot-updates-in-postgresql-for-better-performance/) and creates a new index entry would cause an index page to be split, which is expensive.  This would defy the concepf of setting a `fillfactor` below 100 to prevent excessive page splitting and fragmentation.

With `INSERT`s that are all over the place, like UUIDs for a primary key, many leaf pages will automatically not be filled up completely.